# remove html table columns using sed

Tags: html, linux, parsing, xslt, sed

How to remove html table columns(3rd and 4th columns) using sed?

```
<td>test1</td>
<td>test2</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>test5</td>
```

Comment: what's your OS? If `Linux` - add the respective tag

Comment: you want to remove empty `<td></td>` right?

Comment: It is LINUX.   <td> may be empty or not.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: `sed` is NOT a proper tool for parsing html/xml data. What are your chances to install a proper XML/HTML parsers?

Answer (score 0):

One of the proper ways of doing this is for example to use `XSLT`:

**INPUT HTML:**

```
more table.html 
<html>
        <head>
                <style>
                table, td, th {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }

                table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                th {
                    height: 50px;
                }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>My First Heading</h1>
                <p>My first paragraph.</p>

                <table style="width:100%">
                  <tr>
                        <th>Firstname</th>
                        <th>Lastname</th> 
                        <th>remove</th> 
                        <th>remove</th> 
                        <th>Age</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>Jill</td>
                        <td>Smith</td> 
                        <td>remove</td>
                        <td>remove</td>
                        <td>50</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>test1</td>
                        <td>test2</td>
                        <td>remove</td>
                        <td>remove</td>
                        <td>test5</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

**XSLT:**

```
more table_conv.xslt 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- copy all elements as-is -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- for the following elements 3rd and 4th column and title, don't do anything, they will be ignored -->
    <xsl:template match="//td[3]|//td[4]|//th[3]|//th[4]"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CMD:**

```
xsltproc --html -o table2.html table_conv.xslt table.html
```

**HTML OUTPUT:**

```
more table2.html                                                                                                               
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style>
                table, td, th {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }

                table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                th {
                    height: 50px;
                }
                </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jill</td>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test2</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Explanations:**

See the comments!

**BEFORE:**

[image: before]

**AFTER:**
[image: after]